# Printing first field and (and only) matching fields in record, using awk

Tags: python, awk

I really don't know if awk would be the appropriate tool for that task... Maybe something in python would be better. Anyway, I thought asking here first for the feasibility of the task. Here we go :

Datas :

###

offspr84        175177 200172 312312 310326 338342 252240 226210 **113129** 223264
male28          197175 172200 308312 310338 262338 256252 190226 **113129** 223219
female13        197177 172172 312308 318326 342350 240248 210218 129113 267247

###

offspr85        **181177** 192160 320312 290362 **358330** 238238 214178 133129 263223
male65          197181 176192 320268 322286 **358330** 238244 206214 137133 267263
female17        **181177** 160172 280312 362346 350326 230238 126178 129129 223167

###

So basicaly I need to print the first field ($1) and matching (in bold) $9 in the first record and matching $2 and $6 in second record.

Output file :
offspr84     113129
male28       113129

offspr85     181177
female17     181177

offspr85     358330
male65       358330

Any hint on how I could accomplish that ?

Thanx !

Comment: I forgot to mention, the match is always perform between the fist line of the record and the next two. It should **not** be perform between male and female.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will produce the output you want. Maybe not the best way, but seems to work as expected.

```
#data = [
    #'offspr84 175177 200172 312312 310326 338342 252240 226210 113129 223264',
    #'male28 197175 172200 308312 310338 262338 256252 190226 113129 223219',
    #'female13 197177 172172 312308 318326 342350 240248 210218 129113 267247']

data = [
'offspr85 181177 192160 320312 290362 358330 238238 214178 133129 263223',
'male65 197181 176192 320268 322286 358330 238244 206214 137133 267263',
'female17 181177 160172 280312 362346 350326 230238 126178 129129 223167' ]

for i, line in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = line.split(' ')

for item in data[0]:
    if data[1].count(item) > 0:
        print data[0][0], item
        print data[1][0], item

    if data[2].count(item) > 0:
        print data[0][0], item
        print data[2][0], item
```

Update:

With a nested list to include both list at once:

```
datas = [[
'offspr85 181177 192160 320312 290362 358330 238238 214178 133129 263223',
'male65 197181 176192 320268 322286 358330 238244 206214 137133 267263',
'female17 181177 160172 280312 362346 350326 230238 126178 129129 223167' ],
[
'offspr84 175177 200172 312312 310326 338342 252240 226210 113129 223264',
'male28 197175 172200 308312 310338 262338 256252 190226 113129 223219',
'female13 197177 172172 312308 318326 342350 240248 210218 129113 267247']
]
for data in datas:
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        data[i] = line.split(' ')


for data in datas:
    for item in data[0]:
        if data[1].count(item) > 0:
            print data[0][0], item
            print data[1][0], item

        if data[2].count(item) > 0:
            print data[0][0], item
            print data[2][0], item
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Your code is clear. Now I need the datas t contain multiple record, would you go with a nested list and add a for loop ? I think it would work. Thanx !

Comment: Yes, putting datas in a nested list should do what you need, and go throught the list with a for loop. It should be almost the same code anyway, ask if you didn't manage to get it.

Comment: Ok, I've loaded my file in a nested list : >>> data[0] ['offspr1', '177175', '184188', '280316', '330318', '334342', '236240', '218226', '129129', '263259', 'male30', '193177', '184172', '280308', '330318', '334334', '240236', '238218', '129129','263267', 'female21', '175209', '172188', '312316', '318298', '354342', '258240', '226226', '133129', '259167', ''] But this list has no attribute split, wich make me think there is something wrong with my nested list....

Comment: I've just update my previous answer to include the nested list. Both lists are now compared for matches in the same code. Hope this will answer your needs

Comment: It seems from the 3 examples given that the match must take place between an item in row 0 and an item **in the same column** in either row 1 or row 2. The test `data[1].count(item) > 0` does not honour the "same column" restriction.

Comment: Yes, thank you Nicolas, your code works as expected, I only have problem loading my datas (csv file) in a way so the code would work: This is what I have: ['offspr100', '197177', '200168',....  My datas are loaded as expected (nested list), one line for every offspr,male,female, but the syntax is slightly different from your example. I'm trying to figure it out. Sorry, this question sounds sounds so trivial!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on how you want the matching to work. but assuming the same pattern is applied to all fields, you can easily do this by looping over the fields e.g

```
{
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (match($i, "some regexp")) {
            print $1 $i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a start, but my problem is the match need to be perform between fields, not using a regexp. Let me reformulate : If any of the fields (except field 1) match in a record, print field 1 and the matching field.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean by matching, if it's contained in the first record?

Answer (score 0):

try this awk code

```
 awk '/###/{i++;next}
i==1{if($0~/offspr84/){
        a=$9;n=$1;next;
}

if($9==a){print n,a;print $1,$9}}
        i==2{if($0~/offspr85/){
        m=$1;p=$2;q=$6;next;}
        if($2==p){print m,p;print $1,p}
        if($6==q){print m,q;print $1,q}
}' yourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    /^offspr/ {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            offspr[i] = $i
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i == offspr[i]) {
                print offspr[1] " " offspr[i]
                print $1 " " $i
                print ""
                break
            }
        }
    }
'
```